# File just showed up on my desktop, but no virus

Tags: windows-7, desktop

Yesterday, I turned on my PC to find three new files on my desktop named "emptyness.swf". If I remember correctly, they were actually "emptyness1.swf", "emptyness2.swf", and "emptyness3.swf"; maybe the first one was just called "emptyness.swf". I don't remember.

I tried to open the first file. I don't remember what player it opened to, but it immediately froze and I got the "stopped responding" message. Because the name was a bit creepy, and I had no idea how the files got there, I immediately deleted them.

I ran Avast, Malware Bytes, and Microsoft Security Essentials and came up with nothing. I also ran AVG and it came up with two "inline hook"s, but when I googled the name of the files it showed up as a common Avast/AVG conflict.

While it's less important, I did in fact search up the name of the files before I even ran the scan to know if it's nothing to worry about. I didn't come up with any good results. I did, however, find [an interesting link (NSFW)](http://swfchan.com/10/49209/?emptiness.swf) which was a bit creepy.

The files couldn't have just shown up out of nowhere. Is there anything I can do to find out what put them there?

I have an SSD so the files probably wont be recoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how the files got there, but they have a .swf file extension which is Shockwave Flash (video, etc), and the probable reason they're on your desktop is because some browsers (notably Firefox) set the default download directory to the Desktop folder (hence the file icons show up on your desktop).

You could have a look through your web browser history to see if there are any sites that don't look familiar to you, in order to establish where those files came from. However, as you've deleted those files, run a thorough virus scan with multiple AV programs and you're not seeing any peculiar behaviour, quite honestly I would forget about it and move on.